# Error when getting the Info from Config Server

Tags: spring-cloud

I am configuring an Eureka client app, but always the registered port result in 80.

The server config is obtained from Eureka with auto-discovery enabled, when auto-discovery is disabled the port is registered correctly.

The port of the app is assigned only from the command line (--server.port=8080) and deleted in all other properties files (app.yaml, boostrap.yaml and in the config server git repo)

I have notice that in this code:

EurekaClientConfiguration.java

```
    if (port != 0 && instanceConfig.getNonSecurePort() == 0) {
        instanceConfig.setNonSecurePort(port);
    }
```

The instanceConfig.getNonSecurePort() never is 0, due to this, the nonSecurePort property is never changed.

I have to register the port property in some other place?

Edited to add some detail:

I mean that my bootstrap.yml has the following lines:

```
cloud:config:discovery:enabled: true
```

The yml config is in a github repository and doesn’t have the port assigned

The app is running in the port 8082 with the app param --server.port=8082 But when it is registered in Eureka the port is always 80 instead of 8082

```
<port enabled="true">8082</port>
<securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
```

This cause every based ribbon invocation doesn’t get the correct URL.

I notice that the port is setting correctly in this handler event after the init

EurekaClientConfiguration.java:

```
public void onApplicationEvent(EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent event) {
   ...
   EurekaClientConfiguration.this.port = event.getEmbeddedServletContainer().getPort();
```

But the flag "running" is active now and doesn't have any effect

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What do you mean "The server config is obtained from Eureka with auto-discovery enabled"?  Those three lines in `EurekaClientConfiguration.java` are for testing when the `server.port` is set to zero to get a random assigned port.  You don't have that problem because `instanceConfig.getNonSecurePort() never is 0`.

Comment: Your `cloud:config:discovery: enable: true` is not valid YAML, neither is there such a property (if you fixed the whitespace) - maybe you meant "enabled". I don't think this has anything to do with your port registration though.

Comment: Thanks Dave, sorry was a typo the config is obtained successfully from the github repo: https://github.com/aglwkrs/config
But the registered port doesn’t match with my config:
http://t.co/BQadoNvpBl
When the config server is not discovered the port is registered correctly

Comment: I have a similar issue. My application has port 8890 configured, but it registers in eureka as 8080 and this brakes ribbon routing. Did you solve this?